# "How do you want open this website?" message

Tags: windows-10

After an update for my Windows 10 sound system broke, I uninstalled the update.  When I did, this message started appearing every time I open my PC:

[image]

Comment: your question is currently unclear and can't be answered, please improve it. What is "this update". Which "sound system" do you have? How that's related to the error message? Do you get that error message during browsing? Do you get error message for all websites?

Comment: i get it  while open (this pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the default program for webpages.

You can do this by doing the following: Go to Settings, System, Default Apps.

Find the Web browser setting at the bottom and change it to something else.

If it is currently set to whatever you wish to use, then change it to something else and then back to what you want to use.

If this doesn't work, press the button "Reset to default" which will assign Microsoft Edge, then change it to what you want to use.

Once done, the above popup will show up once more, but now allows you to select your default app and it will remember the setting.